# Finding position vector of cross product

Tags: vector-analysis

I have been stuck trying to find the solution doe this following question:

If a = (-1, 5, r ) b = (-5, 1, 1) and c = (-1, 1, -3) find the values of  for which a x b is perpendicular to a x c. (state lowest first)

I first calculated a x b, which led me to (5-r)i-(-1+5r)j+24k. And b x c = -4i-16j+4k. I then counted the dot product of a x b and b x c

a x b.b x c = -20+4r-16+80r+96

This equals to 0 because they are perpendicular to each other and I ended up with r = 5/7.

I am supposed to submit two values of r. So I don't know what I did wrong and wondering if any of you can help me. It is much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you misread the problem? You should have calculated $a \times c$ not the constant vector $b \times c$, since the wording of the question is to the effect that $a \times b$ should be perpendicular to $a \times c$.

Comment: @coffeemath I did! Thank you for noticing. Can't believe I didn't see it until you mentioned it

Comment: With $r$ in both vectors, likely you'll get a quadratic with two roots.

Answer (score 0):

Hint (Lagrange): 
$$\langle a\times b,c\times d\rangle=\langle a,c\rangle\langle b,d\rangle-\langle b,c\rangle\langle a,d\rangle.
$$

Now happily solve $\langle a\times b,a\times c\rangle=0$.